# How to get the web page's source code with java?(How to deal with delay loading?)

Tags: java, ajax, html, scribe

I want to get the whole(entire) web page's source code, however some contents of the website is not loaded at first.(Seems this have relation with Ajax)
How can I get these contents which are not loaded at once with java?

I tried to use `java's url.openStrem`. But this didn't work. I only got the content "`loading...`" not the real content after loaded.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remote control an existing browser (which is not exactly easy with Java as most use other languages / component systems / interfaces) or use a headless browser that can execute Javascript. [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) would be of the latter category.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I have solved the problem using htmlunit.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a html parser for such thing. [Jericho Htmlparser](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) would be helpful here.

Comment: Thank you all very much. It's very kind of you. This parser seems pretty cool. But it seems analyzes the html file, however the problem I encountered is that I can't get the whole(entire) html file.